# jQuery fadeOut() function doesn't ALWAYS work in Chrome, Firefox, IE

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Sometimes, the slideshow on my website, which uses fadeOut and fadeIn to cycle through three main images will fadeIn a new photo without fading the old one. This doesn't happen every time the page loads though.
My site is here (the slideshow will take 7 seconds to change):
http://codersarepeople.com/v2/

The code I use is this

```
slideshow = new Array('#slideshow1','#slideshow2','#slideshow3');
var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
$(slideshow[i]).fadeIn(125);
var t = setInterval(function() {
 $(slideshow[i%3]).fadeOut(250,function() {
  $(slideshow[(i+1)%3]).fadeIn(250);
 });
 i++;
},7000);
```

Comment: I am being unable to reproduce this problem. Can you please tell us about the environment you are using this website on.

Comment: In Chrome, IE, and firefox, on windows 7.  Sometimes you have to refresh a few times for it to happen.  And remember to wait 7 seconds for the first slide to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the error only occurs when the random variable i = 0.  I just cheated and forced it to either equal 1 or 2.  I still don't know why that was happening though.